# Java google app engine failed at startup, permission denied

Tags: java, google-app-engine

we are suffering, suddenly and without any warning, a serious issue at Google app engine. We are using java and our application refuses to start because the log shows this following error:

> Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory': Post-processing
>   of the FactoryBean's object failed; nested exception is
>   java.security.AccessControlException: access denied
>   ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.com.sun.proxy")

I'm looking at status page and java seems working fine but our app stop to start about 6PM EST today (march 11)

Is there some changes that google made in the webserver container and their permissions? We are lost because it was working fine for months

Comment: I also have the same problem. Did you manage to find anything? I've just got into the office and will raise a support query on Google shortly.

Comment: Hello, not yet. i havent found any answer yet. My site is down and customers are crazy. It is quite strange because older version also suffer from the same issue. I mean it is something that affect all the products we have developed in last year

Comment: I just added a case into GWSC because we havent found any issue in our side, it seems defintely something wrong at google

Comment: I just contact google and it seems there was an issue in their side with a new version of java runtime, they downgrade it for our site and it works now, then it was a purely error from an not announced upgrade (at least we havent received any notice of it)